# One javadoc description for mutiple methods/constants

Tags: java, javadoc

I have this case, with same description for multiple constants.

```
/**
 * same description
 */
public static final String a = "...";

/**
 * same description
 */
public static final String b = "...";

/**
 * same description
 */
public static final String c = "...";

...
```

Is a way to write description one time and use multiple times? Like:

```
/**
 * same description
 */
public static final String a = "...";
public static final String b = "...";

...
```

I want that because  it keeps my code cleaner.

Comment: you could use `{@link package.class#member label}`

Comment: You cannot apply one JavaDoc comment to multiple lines. It would not generate the JavaDoc properly. But since you have two variables, they must be used for two different reasons. I am not sure a single description would be good to have.

Comment: @Ascalonian Them have the same scope(like properties). And in description I write only scope, because their value can be seen which also describe the reasons why is used or not. I can use one or more at the same time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best you can reach is linking the variables one to another with `@link` , something like this

```
/**
 * Description for all methods
 */
public static final String a = "...";

/**{@link #a readDocHere}*/
public static final String b = "...";
/**{@link #a readDocHere}*/
public static static  String c = "...";
```

The link syntax is `{@link package.class#member label}`

Comment: This is not ideal for me. My ideal is to appear direct description. But in the end it helps me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's possible! Glad to have helped ! :)

Comment: That's what I think too

Comment: I found another solution, but that makes the path a bit longer to them. Create a inner class with description and in that class have all constants.